# Retrieve powershell variable in azure devops task and assign to terraform conf

Tags: powershell, variables, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have an Azire Devops release pipeline, in which i have a task executing a powershell script. In this script, i retrieve the uuid of a (nutanix) vlan according to its name, like this :

```
parameters:
- name: vlan
  displayName: vlan
  type: string
  default: VLAN_DMZ_1
  values:
  - VLAN_DMZ_1
  - VLAN_DMZ_2

steps:
- task: petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell.Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell.InlinePowershell@1
  displayName: 'Check Parameters'
  inputs:
    Script: 
     $NIC = Get-NTNXNetwork | where { $_.name -eq  "${{ parameters.vlan }}" } | select uuid -ExpandProperty uuid
```

How can i retrieve the value of this variable into the .tf file?

I tried this :

```
 nic_list {
    subnet_uuid = "$(NIC)"
  }
```

But it doesn't work (it takes $(NIC) as the value itself), tried the replace token but it does not seem to be what i am looking for.

Thank your for your help.

Comment: As an aside: `select uuid -ExpandProperty uuid` should be `select -ExpandProperty uuid`

Comment: Now, why have i been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to implement would be to define your terraform variable in the `variables.tf` file and then pass the variable through Azure devops pipeline from terraform plan command. For example in the below plan I pass into `environment` terraform variable the azure devops environment parameter.

```
terraform plan -input=false -out=tf_plan -var=environment="${{ parameters.environment }}"
```

Otherwise you could just append the value on the `.tfvars` file that you want. This should be done in powershell

```
Write-Output "subnet_uuid = $(NIC)" >> terraform_folder\terraform.tfvars
```

Comment: The write-output was the easiest solution! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @nyarlath if you resolved the issue consider marking the answer as completed